# How to access a certain group of bytes in a MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, stream, byte

I have a MemoryStream that reads some data during a `do...while` loop, and I need to check the last 5 bytes that have been read.

How can I access the last 5 bytes read in a MemoryStream?

Comment: I thought that `Seek` just sets the position of the stream? If you know how to do what I'm asking, I'd be grateful if you posted an answer.

Comment: Save the last 5 bytes you have read? The stream won't, that's your job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the position to 5 bytes behind, and reread those bytes:

```
byte[] GetLast5BytesRead(MemoryStream stream)
{
    // TODO: Validation that stream.Position is at least 5
    byte[] ret = new byte[5];
    stream.Position -= 5;
    // TODO: Consider throwing an exception if this doesn't return 5
    Stream.Read(ret, 0, 5);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. The only thing I had to change was `stream.Position -= 5;` to `stream.Position -= 6;`

Comment: Wouldn't it do better if you code `stream.Seek(-5, SeekOrigin.Current)` than `stream.Position -= 5;`?

Comment: I personally don't see the difference, but I'd love it if you could explain the benefit.

Comment: It should be noted that `Seek()` works just as well here: `stream.Seek(-5,SeekOrigin.Current)`. In the case of a `MemoryStream`,  if you look at the source code, `Seek()` sets the position directly. Using the `Position` property is a little more efficient, but not by much. For other types of streams (e.g., disk-base i/o), setting the position may well invoke `Seek()` under the hood.